# sprintf stack buffer overflow

Tags: c

I'm trying to store a string in a char variable using sprintf. The code compiles, but when I run it I get a stack buffer overflow error. My compiler gives me information about why there was an error, but I can't tell what is actually wrong.

int numbers[] is an array with length 6, and matchHighest is an integer = 0.

I called match6 in this function:

```
int match(int numbers[], int matchHighest){
    int matchArray[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int i = 0;
    char m6[100] = "";
    char *m6p = m6;
    match6(&numbers[i], matchArray, &m6[100]);
```

Here is where the error is occuring:

```
int match6 (int numbers[], int matchArray[5], char *m6){
    int i=0;
    while((numbers[i]==numbers[i+1]) && (i<5)){
        i++;
    }
    if(i == 5){
        matchArray[4] = 6 * numbers[0] + 27;
        sprintf(m6, "Rule match-6(%d) - score %d", numbers[0], matchArray[4]);
        printf("%s\n", m6);
    }
    return matchArray[4];
}
```

When it runs, I get this error (all the values at the bottom are correct and as expected):

draft6.c:98 runtime error - stack buffer overflow

dcc explanation: access past the end of a local variable.
  Make sure the size of your array is correct.
  Make sure your array indices are correct.

Execution stopped here in match6(4) - score 51") in draft6.c at line 98:

```
if(i == 5){
    matchArray[4] = 6 * numbers[0] + 27;
-->     sprintf(m6, "Rule match-6(%d) - score %d", numbers[0], matchArray[4]);
    printf("%s\n", m6);
}
```

Values when execution stopped:

```
i = 5
m6 = "Rule match-6(4) - score 51"
matchArray[4] = 51
numbers[0] = 4
```

Comment: How are you calling `match6`? It can be that `while((numbers[i]==numbers[i+1]) && (i<5)){` you are accessing `numbers[5]` here.

Comment: See the exact invocation of `match6` would be nice. Along with the declarations of the things you pass in as paramaeters.

Comment: Have you allocated memory in any way for `char *m6` ?

Comment: I edited my post. If you need more info let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match6(&numbers[i], matchArray, &m6[100]);`. You pass the address of the item beyond the last allocated item. After which match6 writes out of bounds. Instead of doing strange things, simply pass the array:

```
char m6[100] = "";
match6(&numbers[i], matchArray, m6);
```